# Метод при скрытии игры

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-editor, unity3d-android

Если на андроиде скрыть игру (любым способом) то она автоматически остановится, и возобновится при последующем открытии с того же места (если не была закрыта). Вопрос, как проверить скрыл ли пользователь игру или нет? т.е. что бы после открытия не возобновлялась игра, а была например открыта панель паузы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У классов-наследников `MonoBehaviour` есть методы [.OnApplicationFocus(bool)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus.html) и [.OnApplicationPause(bool)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationPause.html). Подробнее об условиях их вызова можете узнать из документации.

Определив их в одном из ваших классов, которые находятся на игровом поле вы можете как-то реагировать на эти события.

Например, какой-нибудь класс "игровое поле", когда он узнает, что фокус потерян или игра встала на паузу - он открывает окно паузы и игру останавливает.

Comment: спасибо, о паузе слышал но почему то забыл, а про фокус впервые.